understanding something in strtok() (C)
in the following code, i dont understand what exactly happens behind the scenes in the following line:
token = strtok(NULL, s);
if strtok recives as a first argument the string in which you want to do the tokenizing in, how come all of a sudden NULL is being used in that context?
im a begginer c programmer trying to figure it out,
i appriciate the help!
int main () {
   char str[80] = "This is - www.tutorialspoint.com - website";
   const char s[2] = "-";
   char *token;
   
   /* get the first token */
   token = strtok(str, s);
   
   /* walk through other tokens */
   while( token != NULL ) {
      printf( " %s\n", token );
    
      token = strtok(NULL, s);
   }
   
   return(0);
}


Welcome to SO. That function simply stores intermediate data in some static variable and uses it when called with NULL. It does not use it when you provide something else.

If you really want to know the details, you can search for the source code of some C libarary and check how it is implemented.
